# Different ways to get Inputs in Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

What are the different ways to get inputs in Java?

I have used two methods:

`BufferedReader` and

`Scanner`

Are there any other ways to get Inputs?

If so what is the difference between them?

Comment: Type same on Google if its working at your end.

Comment: There are several more types of readers, feel free to read up on it and ask specific questions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html

Comment: @AchintyaJha Sir, I hope most of the questions here, first find their way through Google and come here when they need more explanation.

Comment: @Swamy Good. But you have to be specific where you having problem.

Comment: @AchintyaJha Sir, I searched about it in Google. But there are many ways. But what I am confused is that, can one method of getting input from user can be applied everywhere or for each scenario we should use different methods. Am a beginner in Java.

Answer (score 3):

well i tried a few ways to see the possibilities on how to inputs through different objects and i explored it in 4 different ways

```
     public String input1()
{
    System.out.println("enter the input");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1=sc.nextLine();
    return s1;
}
public String input2()throws IOError
{

    Console c=System.console();
    String s2=null;
    s2=c.readLine("enter the value");
    return s2;
}
public String input3()
{
    System.out.println("enter the input");
    String s3=javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the text");
    return s3;

}
public String input4()throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("enter the input");
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    String s4=br.readLine();
    return s4;
}
```

if i come across anymore i'll be sure to list it down here

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Console class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

An example of its use:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79